# How do I tell Bing Maps to always default to “automatic” view?

Tags: bing-maps, bing

Bing Maps offers three views:

- Road
- Birds-Eye
- Automatic, which switches between Road and Birds-Eye view depending on your zoom level.

I want Bing Maps to always come up in Automatic view, but I can’t seem to find a setting for it. Every time I use a map it starts out in Road view.

I tried logging in (thinking it might save my view), and I’ve tried the “Preferences” link in the upper-right corner (there was nothing relevant).

How do I default to Automatic view?